# Sum column values in redshift based on condition

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want a table containing customerid, login timestamp, logout timestamp and sessions duration. Currently I have a table with a customerid, login timestamp, logout timestamp and duration between events. I want to consider all rows where mindiff is below 20 as part of the same session.

[image: Snippet of table]

So the above table would result in the table below, where the mindiff 160 is the cutoff between sessions.

[image: snippet of the table i want]

---

Is it possible to sum mindiff based on the condition and preserve the login and logout dates ?

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? Although they share some very ancient roots, they are quite different

Comment: Edit -> on redshift

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a "session" value using a cumulative sum.  Then filter and aggregate:

```
select customer, min(login), max(logout)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when mindiff >= 160 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by customerid order by login) as grp
      from t
     ) t
where mindiff < 160
group by grp, customerid;
```